# How to make per- http Request cache in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-3.5, request

We using ASP.NET 3.5 (Controls-based approach) and need to have storage specific for one http request only.

Thread-specific cache with keys from session id won't work because threads are supposed to be pooled and therefore I have a chance to have data from some previous request in cache, which is undesirable in my case. I always need to have brand new storage for each request available through whole request.

Any ideas how to do it in ASP.NET 3.5?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We have used [HttpContext.Current.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) collection to do RequestScope caching. It works well.

Comment: Important- using await or using multiple threads can cause HttpContext.Current to be different or null.

Answer (score 6):

just to clarify what ggonsalv was referring to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx

```
HttpContext.Items["key"] = value;
```

UPDATE: the mvc specific version

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Context collection. This allows data to be shared between all your controls but only lasts for the request.

Use it like this 
context.Items("base_url") = "default.aspx"

Comment: Duh. Got a call.. but house9 got it on the **head**

HttpContext.Items["key"] = value;

or 
context.Items("base_url") = "default.aspx"